# Business Catalyst - Photo Gallery : default thumbnail size

Tags: responsive-design, thumbnails, photo-gallery, business-catalyst

How can i set a default thumbnail size in smaller resolution? Because at the moment it is very tiny in 320x480 resolution.

Comment: This is the photoshttps://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/10258554_10201292633717274_3197847678246360466_n.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the image, the link doesn't work however this will target all images, just replace `img` with your CSS class/ID and change the `min-width` value to the minimum width you would like the photos to be. Bearing in mind if you're making smaller images appear bigger, they will look blurry.

```
img { min-width: 80px; height: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the Photo Gallery module? If so you can simply apply width and height parameters to the module tag and it will automatically set the thumbnail size for you.

Basically the module syntax is as follows:

```
{module_photogallery,ID,rowLength,targetFrame,resultsPerPage,Width,Height,UseStandardMethod,ThumbnailAlgorithm}
```

So, if you wanted to set the thumbnail size at 480x640 for example, you would enter the following:

```
{module_photogallery,XXXXX(ID #),,,,480,640}
```

The **thumbnail algorithm** is very useful - be sure to read up about it along with further details here: http://kb.worldsecuresystems.com/134/bc_1345.html#main_Photo_Gallery_Modules